# Why isn't my BIND configuration correct?

Tags: localhost, bind

I'm new to all this and want to create a new zone called "example.net". I want this domain to be interlinked with my current virtual machine's IP address 192.168.1.4. 
When I run the command:

```
sudo nslookup example.net localhost
```

it returns an error message:

```
    Server:     localhost
    Address:    127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find www.example.net: SERVFAIL
```

What is the problem, and what does the character "@" stand for? Thanks!

/etc/bind/db.example.net

```
;
; example.net
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.example.net root.example.net (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.example.net
@       IN      A       192.168.1.4
ns1     IN      A       192.168.1.4
```

/etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "example.net" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.example.net";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add the root domain (.) to the end of the domain names.
e.g ns1.example.net.

Comment: A fairly common issue :)

Answer (score 1):

First try reloading Bind's configuration with `rndc reload` or restart Bind service. Check the logs in `/var/log` for any errors.

One thing that I've spotted was:

```
@       IN      NS      ns1.example.net
```

Try changing it to:

```
@       IN      NS      ns1.example.net.
```

Notice the '.' at the end of the FQDN.

@ means that the rest of the DNS record following it applies to the FQDN itself, i.e. to example.net instead of i.e. www.example.net.