# DNS named and zone file config help

Tags: dns, 12.04

I'm seeing the following dns resolving errors on the Ubuntu server.

```
Jan  7 14:46:17 xrmt5 named[5140]: error (network unreachable) resolving '225.11.1.1.lab-map.abc.com/A/IN': 2001:500:2f::f#53
Jan  7 14:46:17 xrmt5 named[5140]: error (network unreachable) resolving '225.11.1.1.lab-map.abc.com/A/IN': 2001:500:1::803f:235#53
```

what am  I missing in the named/zone config files?

In /etc/named.conf I already have this:

```
zone "lab-map." {
        type master;
        file "/var/named/lab_map";
};
```

In /var/named/lab_map I have this:

```
                IN   NS      xrmt5.abc.com.
1.1.11.225      IN    A      1.1.1.1
225.11.1.1      IN    A      2.2.2.2
1.1.1.232       IN    A      10.30.0.201
                IN    A      10.40.0.202
```

An `uname -a` gives:

```
Linux xrmt5 3.11.0-15-generic #25~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:39:31 UTC 2014
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example configuration in the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/570898/why-isnt-my-bind-configuration-correct/570907#570907).
Your zone name has a dot at the end and your zone file is missing a SOA definition.